# How to test a promise that connects to RabbitMQ?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing

Hi I'm using Chai and trying to test a custom function that connects to RabbitMQ passing a wrong host:

```
connect(host) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      amqp.connect(host)
        .then((conn) => {
          resolve(conn);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          throw new Error(err);
        });
    });
  }
```

If the connection fail I throw a Error, so I'm testing it like this:

```
it('shouldnt connect to RabbitMQ service successfully with the wrong host.', async () => {
      const result = await rabbitmqmailer.connect('amqp://wronghost');
      expect(result).to.equal(Error);
    });
```

The connection fails and throws a error but my test is not testing that, simply I got the exception on my terminal:

```
RabbitMQMailer component.
    RabbitMQMailer configuration information.
      ✓ should test rabbitmqmailer host configuration.
      ✓ should test rabbitmqmailer queue configuration.
      ✓ should get rabbitmqmailer empty emailContent value after make a new instance.
      ✓ should get rabbitmqmailer empty emailContentConsumed value after make a new instance.
      ✓ resolves
      ✓ should connect to RabbitMQ service successfully with the correct host. (60ms)
Unhandled rejection Error: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN wronghost wronghost:5672
    at _amqplib2.default.connect.then.catch.err (/home/ubuntu/Desktop/easy-tracking/backend/src/components/rabbitmqmailer/rabbitmqmailer.dal.js:1:11069)
    at tryCatcher (/home/ubuntu/Desktop/easy-tracking/backend/node_modules/amqplib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/ubuntu/Desktop/easy-tracking/backend/node_modules/amqplib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/ubuntu/Desktop/easy-tracking/backend/node_modules/amqplib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/ubuntu/Desktop/easy-tracking/backend/node_modules/amqplib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/ubuntu/Desktop/easy-tracking/backend/node_modules/amqplib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:690:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/home/ubuntu/Desktop/easy-tracking/backend/node_modules/amqplib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (/home/ubuntu/Desktop/easy-tracking/backend/node_modules/amqplib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/ubuntu/Desktop/easy-tracking/backend/node_modules/amqplib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/ubuntu/Desktop/easy-tracking/backend/node_modules/amqplib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:632:19)

      1) shouldnt connect to RabbitMQ service successfully with the wrong host.
```

I tried catching the exception on a trycatch block but it's the same issue.

**EDIT**: I got this error on terminal after changing my test to:

```
it('shouldnt connect to RabbitMQ service successfully with the wrong host.', async (done) => {
      const result = await rabbitmqmailer.connect('amqp://wronghost');
      expect(result).to.be.an.instanceof(Error);
      done();
    });


(node:18911) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN wronghost wronghost:5672
    at _amqplib2.default.connect.then.catch.err (/home/ubuntu/Desktop/easy-tracking/backend/src/components/rabbitmqmailer/rabbitmqmailer.dal.js:1:11475)
    at tryCatcher (/home/ubuntu/Desktop/easy-tracking/backend/node_modules/amqplib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/ubuntu/Desktop/easy-tracking/backend/node_modules/amqplib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/ubuntu/Desktop/easy-tracking/backend/node_modules/amqplib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/ubuntu/Desktop/easy-tracking/backend/node_modules/amqplib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/ubuntu/Desktop/easy-tracking/backend/node_modules/amqplib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:690:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/home/ubuntu/Desktop/easy-tracking/backend/node_modules/amqplib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (/home/ubuntu/Desktop/easy-tracking/backend/node_modules/amqplib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/ubuntu/Desktop/easy-tracking/backend/node_modules/amqplib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/home/ubuntu/Desktop/easy-tracking/backend/node_modules/amqplib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:632:19)
(node:18911) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:18911) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
      1) shouldnt connect to RabbitMQ service successfully with the wrong host.


1) RabbitMQMailer component.
       RabbitMQMailer configuration information.
         shouldnt connect to RabbitMQ service successfully with the wrong host.:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/home/ubuntu/Desktop/easy-tracking/backend/src/components/rabbitmqmailer/rabbitmqmailer.test.js)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not properly failing. You forgot about the `reject`. Do this instead:

```
connect(host) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      amqp.connect(host)
        .then((conn) => {
          resolve(conn);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          reject(new Error(err)); // Pass the error to reject
        });
    });
  }
```

In your test, use [`instanceof`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_instanceof) to match the `Error` that is returned:

```
it('shouldnt connect to RabbitMQ service successfully with the wrong host.', async () => {
      const result = await rabbitmqmailer.connect('amqp://wronghost');
      expect(result).to.be.an.instanceof(Error);
    });
```

---

Also I don't know what you are using for testing, but if it is `jest`, then this [link](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous.html#resolves-rejects) might help you properly test the promise.

**EDIT**: Actually nvm. I see you are using Chai

Comment: OK, that's better because it doesn't show me that error with red color text I think that my testing is catching that now, but it doesn't pass the test.. I'm expecting an `Error` instance to be equal but it fails why? PD: yes I'm using Chai

Comment: That doesn't work too :( I added the log error (edit)

Comment: @maudev try [`chai-as-promised`](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/) which allows you to test promises with chai

Answer (score 1):

You need to `reject` the Promise.

```
connect(host) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      amqp.connect(host)
        .then((conn) => resolve(conn))
        .catch((err) => reject(new Error(err));
   });
}
```

And the test

```
it('shouldnt connect to RabbitMQ service successfully with the wrong host.', () => {
  return rabbitmqmailer.connect('amqp://wronghost')
    .then(() => { assert.fail('was not supposed to succeed'); })
    .catch((err) => { expect(err).to.be.an.instanceof(Error); })
})
```

Comment: Thanks, the line `.catch((err) => reject(new Error(err));` solved the exception but it fails the test, I did the same like you

Comment: could you please post the new "fail" massage ?

Comment: @maudev see my edit and try again please. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @Heimer Barcos Ok I tried but i got this error: 

`1) RabbitMQMailer component.
       RabbitMQMailer configuration information.
         shouldnt connect to RabbitMQ service successfully with the wrong host.:
     Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.
      at rabbitmqmailer.connect.then.catch.err (src/components/rabbitmqmailer/rabbitmqmailer.test.js:73:9)`

Answer (score 0):

You usually want your tests to be isolated. I would recommend mocking your `amqp` object and expect that the `connect` method is being called.

It's important that you try and understand the real `connect` method before designing the mock

You can use a mocking framework like https://sinonjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the way to test it

```
it('shouldnt connect to RabbitMQ service successfully with the wrong host.', (done) => {
      (async () => {
        try {
          await rabbitmqmailer.connect('amqp://wronghost');
        } catch (error) {
          chai.assert.typeOf(error, 'error');
        } finally {
          done();
        }
      })();
    });
```

But there's some strange issue, if I change the type like a 'string' for example, it tells me:

```
(node:26053) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError: expected [Error: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN wronghost wronghost:5672] to be a string
```

But ! the test passes successfully :

```
 ✓ shouldnt connect to RabbitMQ service successfully with the wrong host.
```

I don't know why it's happen but it works anyway, thanks for the help.